# EF Core No tracking and Add() or Update()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to make my DbContext to work without tracking.

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext() 
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, after every Add(..) or Update(..) I remove the tracking of the new entity:

```
_context.Users.Add(user);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

The problem arises if I add (or update) a new entity that has a reference to an already existing entity (meaning already stored in the database).

For example:

```
var section = new Section();
_context.Sections.Add(section);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
_context.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Detached;

...

var user = new User
{
   Name = "Alex",
   Section = section
}

_context.Users.Add(user);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Results in an error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you're jumping through hoops to be able to work with one context instance. You should use new context instances instead.

Comment: @GertArnold But wouldn't the same issue persist? Considering that there would not be no tracking, I would expect the same exception to be thrown even with a new context. I will double check if that is the case. In the case you were suggesting to keep the tracking: this means that in order to compare an old entity state with a new one I would need to create another context in the same request?

Comment: *I would expect the same exception* Not when using a new context in each of the three code snippets containing `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Might be worth checking through the `dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries` in debug mode, at the points where you're adding/updating and where it's throwing the error, and seeing if the key is already there. If it is, then presumably you've missed a `Detach`.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem in my Blazor server app with the Entity framework.

Even if I detach the saved object, referenced property object was still tracked.
Instead of detaching I'm calling a clear function on the tracker:

```
_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

Comment: This is a bit of a late response, but wouldn't it be easier if you utilized DbContextFactory in your blazor server app?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0#database-access

Comment: Where should we add change tracker?

Comment: I added it after the SaveChanges call in my previous projects. But now I am rather using DbContextFactory to create dbContext for each "unit of work" so unwanted tracking is no problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this problem in two ways, depending on what you do with the newly added entity afterwards:

1. Re-attach the section before using it for a new user:

   ```
   _context.Sections.Attach(section)
   var user = new User
   {
      Name = "Alex",
      Section = section
   }
   ```
2. Only add the section's primary key to the user, e.g. for a 1-n relation:

   ```
   var user = new User
   {
      Name = "Alex",
      SectionId = section.Id
   }
   ```